# Why do some files in Windows not have extensions?

Tags: windows-7

A prominent and common example of this is the hosts file in C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc.  I'm curious what the purpose of having files without extensions is.

Comment: What is the purpose of having a file with an extension?

Comment: @Blender - typically to associate it with a program to open it.

Comment: What about mime types? Tons of files in Linux don't have extensions, yet can be opened with their respective programs.

Comment: The files of the `etc` folder are some sort of (undefined?) inter-OS standard. They share the same names and syntax on linux. Also, what has this to do with software development?

Comment: I think in this case it's because they got the idea (a long, long time ago) from how Unix systems structured their layouts (the `etc` folder for example), and `hosts` is named the same way (without `.txt`) in Unix systems. In fact Windows has some influence from the BSD lineage, I think Windows' `ftp.exe`, if I remember, is pretty much the same as BSD's `ftp` program.

Comment: The OP asked about Windows ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While filename suffixed extensions under windows are fairly ubiquitous, they are not necessary, they are more of a convenience to give the OS a cue as to which application should open the file if double clicked.

You could choose to forego extensions entirely - for example renaming mydocument.doc to mydocument.  All that would happen is that you would need to either say which application should open the file when prompted if you double-clicked it, or open Word first and use it to open the file.

An .exe file also doesn't need an extension, though it may be harder to get them to execute - one way would be from a command prompt: `start <executable>` for example.

The `hosts` file doesn't have an extension because the tcp/ip implementation on Windows followed the unix implementation, with a bit of cludging, and now it is stuck that way for legacy reasons.

Answer (score -2):

IMHO  hosts is without extension for historical reasons, I guess it's some kind of old lanman legacy. (which probably is also some kind of legacy with Unix like hosts file)

Comment: -1 for guessing, and guessing wrong.